# oracle multi user function

Tags: database, oracle, function

How can I create a function that I can use from different users? It must work like built-in oracle function, which can be called from any user. I guess that this can be achieved by granting some privilege..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it for specific users:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON your_function TO some_user;
```

You can allow access to all users this way:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON your_function TO PUBLIC;
```

To reference this function from another users account, do this:

```
SELECT owner.your_function FROM dual;
```

If you want to avoid specifying the owning schema in the function reference, create a public synonym for it:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM your_function FOR owner.your_function;
```

Then anyone can reference the function this way:

```
SELECT your_function FROM dual;
```

Comment: @AlexHoppus, you should avoid the public synonym if at all possible as it clutters the global namespace (if you call anything by the same name things start breaking) and you have to do a [_tiny_ amount of extra work to access via a synonym.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040486/public-synonyms-vs-username-object-pattern-while-connectiong-with-other-users/10042117#10042117)

Comment: Agree with Ben that public synonyms should (as a main rule) be avoided, but would recommend to use regular synonyms on the accessing schema (instead of avoiding all use of synonyms). This would make the accessing code more easily portable if f.ex. there are development and test database schemas on the same db instance with different schema names.