# What to do to define PUBLIC Oracle function callable from any schemas WITHOUT specifying schema's name?

Tags: oracle, function, public, synonym

I have writen a new Oracle function named TO_X_NUMBER on a common schema named COMMOX.

Every time I will use this function **from another schema**, I must prefix the function's name by schema's name like this

```
select COMMOX.TO_X_NUMBER('123,98') from DUAL;
```

What can I do to use this function without specifying the schema's name like in following SQL command ?

```
select TO_X_NUMBER('123,98') from DUAL;
```

Comment: This question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320470/oracle-multi-user-function. The answer are same but when I post a question on Google (I have tried a lot before posting my question), I found nothing ! The question now is what is the more important ? The question or the answer ? Personnaly, it is the question because distinct question can have same answer. I will add that title of other question that is 'Oracle multi user function' has low meaning for me !

Comment: Duplicates acts as signposts, so someone else searching for either will end up at the same (I would suggest slightly more comprehensive) answer. The answer, and both questions, are important.

Comment: @Alex Poole: you write that answer AND question (BOTH) are important. If what you write is correct, I can say that answer AND question are also important to determine when a question/answer is duplicate ! My question is different from previous post so, my question/answer is not a duplicate ! If you agree, can you remove "marked as duplicate" properties from my question. If NO, can you explain your choice as I explain mine ?

Comment: I don't really see why the questions are significantly different. I also don't see why this being marked as a duplicate is a problem. If that is removed then someone doing your original search hopefully now finds this question and sees your answer; with the duplicate marked they still see that, but also can easily click through to the more comprehensive answer if they want. Your question and answer still stand. What do you expect to happen if it is removed - that you get further answers added here (since you haven't accepted your own), which will probably just duplicate the effort elsewhere?

Comment: [Related Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315293/266304); though there are many others, and I'm sure some argue the other way. I'm not convinced this is even borderline, but I can see others would disagree; even if it is, I agree with those Meta answers. And of course, there's nothing stopping anyone disagreeing with my viewpoint flagging the question for reopening.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The Meta post is interesting to see that some other users think as me :-) but others not. I thought that my post will be removed when is it marked as DUPLICATE, but it seems that it is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solution: create a synomym for TO_X_NUMBER function like this

```
create PUBLIC synonym TO_X_NUMBER for COMMOX.TO_X_NUMBER;

grant execute on TO_X_NUMBER to PUBLIC;
```